# CMake 3.11 Linking CUBLAS

Tags: cmake, cuda, cublas

How do I correctly link to *CUBLAS* in *CMake 3.11*?

In particular, I'm trying to create a **CMakeLists** file for [this code](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/05/31/matrix-multiplication-cuda-cublas-curand-thrust/).

**CMakeLists** file so far:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(cmake_and_cuda LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)
add_executable(mmul_2 mmul_2.cu)
```

This gives multiple "undefined reference errors" to cublas and curand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution which is to add this line in the end of the **CMakeLists** file:

```
target_link_libraries(mmul_2 -lcublas -lcurand)
```